# How to call methods from class located in one python file from another python file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating framework using Selenium and Python.
    My data driven Framework should consist of (so far) 3 files:

```
1) Config.py have class Config() that have all the nessesary methods such as: 
   def setUp() - 
   def tearDown()
   def click()
   def send_keys()

2) data.py - with all data 

3) test.py - with all of the steps
```

I am currently working on click() method.

I want to pass 2 parameters to this method, it will use slice() 
    to identify what kind of locators i am using and click 
    accordingly. Unfortunatly no matter what i do - it keeps 
    throwing me some errors.

**config.py:**

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

class Actions(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


    def click(self, elemLocator, elemValue):
        elp = elemLocator
        flp = slice(0,2)
        if elp[flp] == 'id':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_id(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'xp':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'li':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'na':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_name(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'cs':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'pa':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'ta':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass
        elif elp[flp] == 'cl':
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(elemValue).click()
            except:
                pass


    def send_keys(self):
        pass
```

**test.py:**

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from Setup import Actions

action = Actions()
action.setUp()
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a./Desktop/Automation_Work/correct_PPLS/oop/Test.py", line 9, in <module>
    action = Actions()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[Finished in 0.153s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `__init__` as below.

```
def __init__(self,driver=None):
    if driver != None:
        self.driver = driver
```

Now you can call the `__init__` with or without passing driver. However, I suggest declaring the driver out side the class and make it as global so that you can access it anywhere.

Something like this:

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
driver = None
class Actions(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def setUp(self,browserName):
        global driver 
        if browserName == 'chrome' #<==== creating the driver based on browser (you can pass this as argument while calling this method)
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        # return driver #<==== return driver so that you can store with other name if you are planning to launch 2nd instance of driver.

action = Actions()
action.setUp("chrome")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an instance of the class if you're calling a method that is not static.

I'm not sure if you're using Python 2 or 3, but here's how you make your methods static in 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling `Action()` with no parameters.  You're effectively calling `Action.__init__(self)`, without providing the `driver` parameter.  That is why you're getting `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.  The 1 given is `self`, which is automatically supplied by Python, and the missing one is `driver`.

Comment: i am still new to coding and trying to figure out. so if i change it this way : action = Actions(driver) it throws me an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a./Desktop/Automation_Work/correct_PPLS/oop/Test.py", line 9, in <module>
    action = Actions(driver)
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
[Finished in 0.162s]

Comment: Your `__init__` method has a parameter named `driver`.  You must supply a value for it.  The value does not have to be named `driver`, and probably shouldn't be in this case.  Based on your setUp, I'm guessing you want it to be `webdriver.Chrome()`.